# Problem With WPF Application And SQL Server Database

Tags: .net, sql-server, wpf

I made an application with animations in WPF with Visual Studio 2008 Team System and SQL Server 2005.

So I have Windows XP and Windows 7, in Windows XP that I have Visual Studio and SQL Server and Framework 3.5 it works very well, but in Windows 7 and in other computers it can not connect to database, first I thought it's about Framework but in other computers I have this problem again.

My connection string is:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"|DataDirectory|safedb.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

What do you think?  I must install Visual Studio in every computer?

What is the problem?

---

this is the code of that button which has error in another computer that doesn't have Visual Studio :

```
            login l = new login();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"|DataDirectory|safedb.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        con.Open();
        String sql = "EXEC GetLoginModel";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        bool n = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
        bool s = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1];
        l.radioButton1.IsEnabled = n;
        l.radioButton2.IsEnabled = s;
        con.Close();
        this.Close();
        l.Show();
```

---

yes I knew but i thought we need this program only when we want to make databases not using it ...

i saw a lot of softwares that they work with mssql but they are tiny and they don't need any other program to install ???

so what ?

and please give me the link of sql server express edition only for using with my app ...

it means i must place that besides of my app ???

Thanks A Lot Again My Sweet Friend :X

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this database `safedb.mdf` on every computer? That would be the first thing to 
check..... (since you're attaching a local database file - not connecting to a central server)

---

OK; so you do have the files on all computers.

Next question: you mention you get an error on the "other"  computers.

**WHAT** is the error exactly? Can you give us the exact error message, an error code possibly?.....

---

I almost don't dare to ask: you do know that in order to attach a SQL Server Express database on a computer, you have to have SQL Server Express installed on that machine?? Have you installed it as the "SQLExpress" named instance on each and every machine?

I ask since you only mention "WPF" and ".NET Framework 3.5" (which both don't include SQL Server Express........)

Windows 7 comes with the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 pre-installed, so you definitely have .NET and WPF on those computers right from the beginning....

Marc